# QNX_CONFIGURATION settings error after Blackberry NDK installation

Tags: sdk, qnx, blackberry-10

I've installed Blackberry Native SDK for Windows 7 but I get the following error when I open the application after installation:

"There is an error in the QNX configuration settings. Either de QNX_CONFIGURATION environment variable is not defined correctly or the location it points to is not accesible.
Exit the IDE and fix the error?"

I guess the solution is as easy as setting the indicated environment variable to the correct path. But i don't know the path it must point to. Does anybody know?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It needs to point to the directory that contains the BlackBerry Native SDK qconfig folder.  In Windows it is probably "C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Native SDK".

Comment: Thanx Erin. It didn't work, either. I finally tried to install it on another computer and worked at first try, with no problem at all. But there was no way to install it properly in the first one.